# Trying to scrape web data from url uses frame. Get data in MSHTML.HTMLDocument obect. I want to save the object as .xls on hard disk

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I want to scrape data from an URL . I am using VBA in excel. I am able to get the data in the MSHTML.HTMLDocument iframeDoc object. Now I want to save the data in the iframeDoc object as an excel file on hard disk.
None of the properties like iframeDoc.Documentelent.innerHTML work .It gives runtime error. Object does not support the property. So I need help to convert the object to string type or any other method to save to hard disk.
Thanks.

I tried properties of MSHTML.HTMLDocument DocumentElemnt and Body to save to string. Those give run time error.

```
 Sub

    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Dim url As String

url = "http://www.1line.williams.com/Transco/info-postings/notices/critical-notices.html"
Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate url

While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend

Set doc = ie.document

Dim iframeDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set iframeDoc = doc.frames.Item("theiframe")

If iframeDoc Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "IFrame with name 'iframename' was not found."
    ie.Quit
    Exit Sub
Else
'*** to save iframeDoc object as .xls file on hard disc ***

Dim strframe As String
   strframe = CStr(iframeDoc.DocumentElement.innerHTML) ' Run time error 
    'object does not support the property or method
   End If
  End Sub
```

I expect iframedoc.DocumentElement.innerHTML to be converted to string.But it gives run time error object does not support the property or method.

Comment: Try `iframeDoc.document.DocumentElement.innerHTML`

Comment: The version I'm using has no property as iframe.document..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow enough time for javascript to run and populate table within the iframe. I used a timed loop for this

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, ws As Worksheet
    Dim hTable As HTMLTable, t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10              '<==Adjust wait time
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "http://www.1line.williams.com/Transco/info-postings/notices/critical-notices.html"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        t = Timer
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            With .document.getElementById("theiframe").contentDocument.getElementById("j_idt11")
                Set hTable = .getElementsByTagName("table")(1)
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While hTable Is Nothing
        If Not hTable Is Nothing Then
            WriteTable hTable, 1, ws
        End If
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub WriteTable(ByVal hTable As HTMLTable, Optional ByVal startRow As Long = 1, Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim tRow As Object, td As Object, r As Long, c As Long
    r = startRow
    With ws
        Dim headers As Object, header As Object, columnCounter As Long
        Set headers = hTable.getElementsByTagName("th")
        For Each header In headers
            columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
            .Cells(r, columnCounter) = header.innerText
        Next header
        For Each tRow In hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            r = r + 1: c = 1
            For Each td In tRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
                If td.classname = "ui-col-7" Then  'or you could use if c = 7
                    .Cells(r, c).Value = "http://www.1line.williams.com" & Replace$(Split(Split(td.outerhtml, "href=" & Chr$(34))(1), ">")(0), Chr$(34), vbNullString)
                Else
                    .Cells(r, c).Value = td.innerText
                End If
                c = c + 1
            Next td
        Next tRow
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Downloads the web content except the column contents of the last column "Download". This column has image with hyperlink and this is empty.Any way to scrape this column too. Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected result? The link?

Comment: If you click below link you will see the last column as Downoad.This has image with hyperlinks. With the above code this column I get empty. I need this column too.The link is:  
http://www.1line.williams.com/Transco/info-postings/notices/critical-notices.html
Thanks.

Comment: Are you expecting the image as well? Or just the link?

Comment: Updated to write out download links.

Comment: Yes now I get the link to column download but the extra html "amp;" is getting added after the "&" , so the link does not work.For example: 1line.williams.com/1Line/wgp/… you can see the amp; after each & sign.
Did a replace of"&amp;" with "&" works fine. Thanks a ton

Comment: Sorry I missed that!